# Append a variant of strings to an empty variant array

Tags: vba

I would like to repeatedly append an array of string values to a master array, which is initially empty. I cannot get it to append.

```
Sub main()

    Dim num As Integer, root As String, pathToFile As String, allOf As Variant, someOf As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, opts() As String, val As Integer
    root = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    pathToFile = root & "\" & "name" & ".txt"

    num = 5  ' the number of files I may have

    For i = 0 To num - 1  ' loop over all the files
        ReDim Preserve opts(i)
        someOf = read_whole_file(pathToFile)  ' read the file into variant
        For val = LBound(someOf) To UBound(someOf)  ' run through the array
            ' -- append someOf to allOf and loop
            Dim Nmbr As Integer
            On Error Resume Next
            Err.Clear
            If allOf.Value = "Empty" Then
                Nmbr = UBound(allOf)
                allOf(0) = someOf(0)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve allOf(UBound(allOf) + 1)
                allOf(UBound(allOf)) = someOf(val)
            End If
        Next val
    Next i
End Sub

Function read_whole_file(filePath As String) As Variant
    Dim sWhole As String
    Open filePath For Input As #1
        sWhole = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
    read_whole_file = Split(sWhole, vbNewLine)
End Function
```

Contents of the text file :

"
Hello

This

Is a

Text

File
"

Comment: Please edit the question and add `read_whole_file` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is VBA. DOn't use an array use a collection.

```
Sub main()

    Dim num As Integer, root As String, pathToFile As String, allOf As Collection, someOf As Variant
    Set allof = new collection
    Dim i As Integer, opts() As String, val As Variant
    root = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    pathToFile = root & "\" & "name" & ".txt"

    num = 5  ' the number of files I may have

    For i = 0 To num - 1  ' loop over all the files

        someOf = read_whole_file(pathToFile)  ' read the file into variant
        For Each val In someOf ' run through the array
            alloff.Add val
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you can add the line `Set allOf = New Collection` after the Dim's I will check your answer off.

Comment: @GeneralCode   Whoops.  Correction now implemented.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you say you have 5 files:

```
   num = 5  ' the number of files I may have
```

but you set the `path_to_file` immediately before this. More importantly, you do not change `path_to_file` within the loop, nor do you pass any modifier to `read_whole_file`. So you code will read from the same file 5 times.

You also don't set any value to `allOf` before you use it. You don't even identify what type it is (apart from `Variant`), so checking `.Value` is meaningless and should result in a compile error. Because of your `On Error` statement, that section is probably being ignored, thus the intended action is not occurring.

How to fix:

- Add `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. **Always**.
- Remove the `On Error` handling - if you think you may have some out of bounds issues, then cater for it in the program logic.

**Bonus**: Instead of `ReDim`ming `opts(I)` each time in the loop, you already know how many iterations, so only `ReDim` it once before entering the loop.